# How to convert .ino file into .bin file with "sketch + WiFi settings" from arduinoIDE to upload in S3 ESP8266 by "ESP8266 download tool"?

Tags: embedded, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I want to flash S3 ESP8266 module by "ESP8266 download tool". In arduinoIDE, when my setUp is like, tools->Erase Flash: **only sketch**. I can easily convert the blink.ino code into .bin and can flash it to my S3 ESP8266 module via "ESP8266 download tool", and can really see it's BuiltIn led blinking.

But, when my setUp is like, tools->Erase Flash: **sketch+WiFi settings**. I can convert the blink.ino into .bin and can flash it to my S3 ESP8266 module via "ESP8266 download tool". But unfortunately it doesn't blink. My .ino code is simple.

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
  delay(1000); 
  digitalWrite(4, LOW);
  delay(1000);
}
```

Options selected in ArduinoIDE's Tools,

**Board : NodeMCU 1.0(ESP-12E Module)**

**Flash Size : "4M (No SPIFFS)"**

I think this issue is because of "build options" changes, but I don't know about it's solution.

Is there anyThing that I am missing out ? Please help.

Comment: The erase is done with a separate execution of the esptool before the upload with esptool

Comment: Thanks Juraj for ur response, I don't know anything about execution of the esptool. I can see esptool.py v2.6 while uploading the code to S3 ESP8266 by arduinoIDE for testing. But while flashing .bin (compiled by ArduinoIDE) by "ESP8266 download tool" to the same module, I can't understand any execution of esptool. Will u plz provide me some basic details or information link for that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/espressif/esptool/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thanks for the link Juraj, that was helpful..By the way, my issue got solved. I replaced memory address of .bin file in ESP8266 Download Tool from "0x1000" to "0x00000".

Comment: yes, the esp8266 Arduino sketch binary includes the second stage bootloader on address 0x0000